# react native Image Loading on android faster than IOS

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm building an application where i render many images in swiper, flatlist and i'm using React Native Image Component, but the component loads the images very fast on Android and very slow on iOS, also the caching is better on android than ios although i use force-cache prop, is there any way to improve image performance for ios ?!

Comment: Consider testing [Fastimage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image)

Comment: have you try the other one like reload or only-if-cached ? what is the result?

Comment: Did you get solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`react-native-web-image`](https://github.com/vovkasm/react-native-web-image), it often gives a way faster experience.